# How to deal with @OneToMany relation in REST

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

I'm designing a small `REST` application that allows to perform some basic operations. So far so good, i have following `@Entity` called `Client` that needs to be persisted along side with `@Entity` called `Loan`:

**Client:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "clients")
public class Client{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "CLIENT_ID")
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String email;
    private String phone;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "client")
    private Set<Loan> loans;

    public Client() {}

    public Client(Long id, String name, String surname, String email, String phone) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

   // getters/setters

}
```

**Loan:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "loans")
public class Loan{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CLIENT_ID")
    private Client client;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date startDate = new Date();

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date originTerm;

    private Float maxPossibleAmount;

    private String notes;

    public Loan() {}

    public Loan(Long id, Client client, Date startDate, Date originTerm, Float maxPossibleAmount, String notes) {
        this.id = id;
        this.client = client;
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.originTerm = originTerm;
        this.maxPossibleAmount = maxPossibleAmount;
        this.notes = notes;
    }

 // getters/setters
}
```

Registering Client works flawlessly, via postman, however i can't to understand how to register loan for a specific client. On attempt to do so, `PostMan` refuses to register new loan with the following message:

> {
>       "timestamp": 1504429329213,
>       "status": 400,
>       "error": "Bad Request",
>       "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
>       "message": "JSON parse error: Can not construct instance of com.reborn.xxx.backend.models.Client: no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (1); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.reborn.xxx.backend.models.Client: no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (1)\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@121b34b; line: 3, column: 12] (through reference chain: com.reborn.xxx.backend.models.Loan[\"client\"])",
>       "path": "/api/loans/add"
>   }

**LoanController:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/loans")
public class LoanController extends BaseController {

    @Autowired
    private LoanService loanService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity registerLoan(@RequestBody Loan loan) {
        Loan regLoan = loanService.registerLoan(loan);
        if(regLoan == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this goal?

**UPDATE1:**

**ClientRepository:**

```
@Repository
public interface ClientRepository extends JpaRepository<Client, Long>{
}
```

**LoanRepository:**

```
@Repository
public interface LoanRepository extends JpaRepository<Loan, Long> {
}
```

JSON to add client (works):

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Arthur",
"surname": "Doyle",
"phone": 777458642,
"email": "adoyle@imperial.com"
}
```

JSON to make a loan to specific client(fails):

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "client": "http://loacalhost:8080/api/clients/find/1",
    "startDate": 20170902,
    "originTerm": 20170902,
    "maxPossibleAmount": 5555.0000,
    "notes": null
}
```

Comment: The error message seems to say there is no way to construct a client from only it's ID.

Comment: Can you show code how you are persisting Client and Loan ??

Comment: Erm, im out of ideas how to link to current existing client entity

Comment: @Ashish451 sorry i cant at this moment but i can assure you both  interfaces extended from jparepositories

Comment: Okay as per log problem seems to be that hibernate is trying to get/put client entity with id 1 which doesn't exist in database. so check  your code accordingly

Comment: When im will be able to put code i will do so. I fill database with 3 clients  id 1,2,3 respectively).After that i make loan where i'm trying to link it to client with id 1... as you can see it doesnt work.

Comment: @Ashish451 Topic updated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Loan` is associated with `Client`. So if you want to create a loan for the client use this payload:

```json
POST http://loacalhost:8080/api/loans 
{
    "originTerm": ...
    "maxPossibleAmount": ...
    "notes": ...
    "client": "http://loacalhost:8080/api/clients/1"
}
```

A custom controller is unnecessary.

P.S. Add `@JsonIgnoreProperties("loans")` to `Loan.client` to avoid the stackoverflow exception...

P.P.S. In `@OneToMany` the `fetch` parameter is `FetchType.LAZY` by default so you can avoid it.

Comment: just tried your solution and it didnt work out well. I receive same error as in post but now about string

Comment: @Reborn check my demo project https://github.com/Cepr0/sdr-one-to-many To add `Master` use `POST http://localhost:8080/api/masters` with payload `{
 "name": "master1"
}`. To add `Slave` use `POST http://localhost:8080/api/slaves` with payload `{
 "name": "slave1", 
 "master": "http://localhost:8080/api/masters/1"
}`

Comment: on running `POST http://localhost:8080/api/slaves with payload { "name": "slave1", "master": "http://localhost:8080/api/masters/1" }`{
    "cause": null,
    "message": "No suitable HttpMessageConverter found to read request body into object of type class io.github.cepr0.onetomany.bidi.Slave from request with content type of text/plain;charset=UTF-8!"
}

Comment: @Reborn content-type must be `application/hal+json;charset=UTF-8`, and don't forget to create `Master` first...

Comment: @Reborn don't try to create a new master or slave with previous name - use unique one (see @Column annotation of `name` property). Or just restart the app...

Comment: finally `Slave post` worked perfectly, however i cant to understand how it works...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153626/discussion-between-reborn-and-cepr0).