# Spring Data Rest & Lombok - Exception while adding adding relation

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-rest, lombok

In my project I have 2 entities. Survey and entries to survey. They are in relation one to many (thare can be many entries to one survey).

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "survey_entries")
@TypeDef(name = "SurveyEntry", typeClass = SurveyEntry.class)
public class SurveyEntryEntity extends AbstractEntity {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "survey_id")
    private SurveyEntity survey;

    @NonNull
    @Type(type = "SurveyEntry")
    @Column(name = "responses")
    // JSON db column type mapped to custom type
    private SurveyEntry responses;
}
```

```java
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "surveys")
@TypeDef(name = "Survey", typeClass = Survey.class)
public class SurveyEntity extends AbstractEntity {

    @NonNull
    @Type(type = "Survey")
    @Column(name = "template")
    // JSON db column type mapped to custom type
    private Survey survey;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "survey")
    private List<SurveyEntryEntity> entries;

}
```

I have also created 2 rest repositories using Spring Data Rest:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "survey_entries", path = "survey-entries")
public interface SurveyEntryRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<SurveyEntryEntity, Long> {
}
```

```java
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "surveys", path = "surveys")
public interface SurveyRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<SurveyEntity,Long> {
}
```

I have successfully added survey by rest POST request and I can access it entries (currently empty) by sending GET to `/api/surveys/1/entries`.Now I want to add entry to exisiting survey. And while I can add it by sending POST (content below) to `/api/survey-entries` I have troubles adding it directly as a reference to survey. I'm using POST method with the same content and url `/api/surveys/1/entries`. What is interesting, I'm getting NullPointerException in logs and entry is not inserted but audit modify timestamp in survey is changed. What am I doing wrong? Did I miss same configuration? Or should I use different content?

Content of POST with entry:

```
{      
  "responses": {          
    "question1": "response1",          
    "question2": "response2",          
    "question3": "response3"      
  }  
}
```

Content of POST with survey:

```
{
    "survey": {
        //survey structure
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
08:41:14.730 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod - Failed to resolve argument 1 of type 'org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource'
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: No content to map due to end-of-input; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input
```

@EDIT

I have tried adding entry by POST to `/api/survey-entries` with 'application/hal+json' Content-Type header and content as below, but now I'm getting other exception:

Content:

```
{      
  "survey" : "http://localhost:8080/api/surveys/1",
  "responses": {          
    "question1": "response1",          
    "question2": "response2",          
    "question3": "response3"      
  }  
}
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.domain.SurveyEntity` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('http://localhost:8080/api/surveys/1')
 at [Source: (org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream); line: 1, column: 41] (through reference chain: com.domain.SurveyEntryEntity["survey"])
```

@Edit 2

Added Lombok annotations present on Entity classess

Comment: Show your payloads of every requests, plz

Comment: I have added body of POST with survey but it's working fine, so I don't think it has something to do with my problem.

Comment: See my answer in other topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46025434

Comment: Tried it but now I'm getting different exception. Details in edited question.

Comment: You didn't define association for `responses` property as I see...

Comment: responses in SurveyEntryEntity and survey in SurveyEntuty are Postgres JSON column mapped to my custom types. So there is no need for any relations on them.

Comment: then temporarily exclude this property and test POST without it (your question is not about json type of field, right?..)

Comment: Getting same exceptions as with them included. Questioning only adding objects to collection. JSON columns doesn't have anything with that error as without them I'm getting same exceptions as with them.

Comment: Check my working demo project https://github.com/Cepr0/sdr-one-to-many and try to implement similarly...

Comment: To add `Master` use `POST http://localhost:8080/api/masters with payload { "name": "master1" }`. To add `Slave` use `POST http://localhost:8080/api/slaves with payload { "name": "slave1", "master": "http://localhost:8080/api/masters/1" }`

Comment: Registering the Jackon2HalModule with your ObjectMapper might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatelly problem lied in Lombok annotations which weren't included in sample code. I added them now so any one can see where the problem lies.

I managed to solve it by downgrading Lombok to version (1.16.14) and changing annotation `@AllArgsConstructor` to `@AllArgsConstructor(suppressConstructorProperties = true)`. It's immposible to achieve in later Lombok versions as this property is currently removed.

I have found solution on Spring Data Rest JIRA. There is already issue [DATAREST-884](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-884) mentioning problem and presenting solution/workaround.

Sorry for wasted time while it was impossible to see solution without all the code.

Comment: Did you see this info? https://projectlombok.org/features/configuration `lombok.anyConstructor.suppressConstructorProperties If true, lombok will not generate a @java.beans.ConstructorProperties annotation when generating constructors. This is particularly useful for GWT and Android development.`

Comment: Yes, but I didn't connect it with my use case. I seems that this annotation somehow make entities unable to deserialize from uri. But why this happens is a mystery for my. Now when this param is now removed form Lombok I consider my use case an issue which should be somehow solved without a need to downgrade dependencies.